# Invariant Violation: ViewPagerAndroid has been removed from React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-viewpager

> Invariant Violation: `ViewPagerAndroid` has been removed from `React Native` ... `react-native-viewpager` instead of `react-native`

Yeah. This error was opened on many platforms including here, but I have a different situation. I have never used anywhere. `ViewPagerAndroid` exists only in the `index.android.bundle` file in my project.

1. Do I need to update this file?
2. How can I update?

I have problems on both platforms as `Android` and `iOS`.

As a solution:

1. `react-native-swiper` update
2. Deleting ViewPagerAndroid from `node_modules \ react-native-swiper \ src \ index.js file`
   (I did not encounter `ViewPagerAndroid`. I think I
   have updated this file before)

I tried many similar things, I tried all the solutions I could find on the internet but I couldn't fix this problem.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the latest version of [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) on your `package.json`

As said [here](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper/issues/1101), you can try using the command: `yarn add react-native-swiper@nightly`

Or, you can just run: `npm install --save https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper`

Or: `npm install --save react-native-swiper@*`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with:

delete // `import ViewPager from rn-viewpager;`

add `import ViewPager from @react-native-community/viewpager;`